# How can I edit a crown from a picture in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, shapes, photo-editing

Can someone help me and guide me how to edit the crown on the picture to match with the king wallers logo?
I dont know how to color it partly,make it glow a little and use shades.

[image: logo]
[image: crown]

Comment: What?  I have no idea what you are asking.  Can you show us?

Comment: I edited it with pictures cause pictures failed to upload first time and i didnt noticed.

Comment: What have you tried? Showing *some effort* and asking about specific areas you are having difficulty with would be helpful.

Comment: At first i dont know how to break the crown into parts(seperate layers) to edit for example at first the bottom of the crown then the top.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do. Open it in Photoshop, create a new layer on top, add a gradient to that layer of Green to Pale Yellow. Then play with Blending Modes and clean it up.

Here's it with the layer mode set to Darken and then deleted the color real fast from outside the crown:

[image]

Alternatively you could do a different blending mode, for a different quick result. Here it is on Lighten with the opacity lowered a bit and nothing else changed:

[image]

Just experiment, you'll get it.